# How to get all active users in same page of an application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I came across a requirement where, i need to show in each page how many active users are there. I came across different approach which i dont know what is the best practice used in these scenario
Below are few in my minds.

```
 1. SignalR
 2. Portal programing
 3. Is there any way to do this with google analytics.
```

Application is using angular js, and each page is having Same URL with different parameter. need to display in each page how many users are opened the same route ( page ) and display in top.

Any hint or direction which i can divert my search into will be very helpull. Thank you

Comment: SignalR. easiest.

Comment: How about using WebSockets?

Comment: looking for a best approach used, am sure this is not the first of its kind

Answer (score 2):

SignalR would be easiest. Each time a user connects (loads the page) via SignalR, increment the counter by one, and when a user disconnects (leaves the page), decrement it by one.

Comment: How about pusher, i read pusher is easy and better documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can count total of connection user by using these code

First I need to create a HashSet to store list of connection users

```
public static class ConnectionList
{
    private static readonly HashSet<string> connectedIds = new HashSet<string>();

    public static HashSet<string> ConnectedIds
    {
        get => connectedIds;
        set => ConnectedIds = value;
    }
}
```

Then in the hub I will need to override 2 method OnConnectedAsync and OnDisconnectedAsync

When user connect we will add their connection id to to the hash. If they turn off their browser we will remove out of the hash

```
public class OnlineHub : Hub
    {
        public Task GetTotalAccountConnect()
        {
            return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("TotalClientConnect", ConnectionList.ConnectedIds.Count);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            ConnectionList.ConnectedIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            ConnectionList.ConnectedIds.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
```

The GetTotalAccountConnect method is to get the total connection number